# What is the JVMID?

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic

I joined a new project recently , I see JVMIDs very frequently in the configuration files and 
Somehow I had never come across JVMIDs in my past projects.

Where can I find it documented , is it something specific to the weblogic servers? Is it meant for precisely identifying a JVM in a clustered environment ?

Comment: for example , there is a class that stores the configuration propertiesof the application ,its a singleton class and upon initialization it stores the JVMID .The JVMID is retrieved from an environment variable .

Comment: also I found out that the weblogic appends the JVMID to the jsessionid , separated by "!".

Comment: e.g. a JSESSIONID looks like "1mh0QFnGkFtfsNGSVpcB4Yn3L8zRnCGhJcTxx0Q71Ltz1CyBTyQY!1380954154" . The part after the ! is a JVMID

Comment: Ok see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6438474/289396

Comment: You may also be able to retrieve the JVMID using the `jps` command-line utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVMID is the ID of the current server instance, I don't believe its WLS specfic.

You can get more information around this via this link [JVMID](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JVMId.java.html#line.46)

Also this question might be useful.

[Weblogic Apache plugin and session stickiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871104/weblogic-apache-plugin-and-session-stickiness)